# Animation inside GUI

Tags: unity

Good day. 
I would like to create a "rich" GUI for my game.

How can i add a 3d model to a GUI Button (with continous rotation ) ? 
If I can't add a 3d model to a GUI button, what is the best way to visualize a 3d model rotating ?

Maybe creating a video file or animated gif and adding it to my button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about the new UI system (coming with `UnityEngine.UI`) and not the old GUI system.

If you want to display a 3D model in a `GUIButton`, you can simply use a `Render Texture`. In another part of the scene you display the animated 3D model you want to use and put a camera dedicated to watch it. The main difference between this new camera and the main camera is that the new one doesn't render on screen but in a `Render Texture`. Then you can easily use this `Render Texture` like a regular texture in your UI using `RawImage` component.

- [More about Render Textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html)
- [More about Raw Images](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html)